# RSpec - Undefined method `key?'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, rspec, tdd, shoulda

I'm trying to run a test for rendering templates and ran into the error:

```
undefined method `key?' for 1014:Fixnum
```

The stub of my model's instance works as it should in my route tests but not so much here. What am I doing wrong?

```
describe RestaurantsController do
  let(:restaurant) { FactoryGirl.build_stubbed(:restaurant) }

  describe 'GET #show' do
    before { get :show, restaurant.id }

    it { should render_template('show') }
  end
end
```

**Full Error**

```
 1) RestaurantsController GET #show 
     Failure/Error: before { get :show, restaurant.id }
     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `key?' for 1014:Fixnum
     # /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.0/lib/action_controller/test_case.rb:744:in `html_format?'
     # /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.0/lib/action_controller/test_case.rb:598:in `process'
     # /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.0/lib/action_controller/test_case.rb:65:in `process'
     # /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/devise-3.5.1/lib/devise/test_helpers.rb:19:in `block in process'
     # /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/devise-3.5.1/lib/devise/test_helpers.rb:72:in `catch'
     # /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/devise-3.5.1/lib/devise/test_helpers.rb:72:in `_catch_warden'
     # /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/devise-3.5.1/lib/devise/test_helpers.rb:19:in `process'
     # /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.0/lib/action_controller/test_case.rb:505:in `get'
     # ./spec/controllers/restaurants_controller_spec.rb:15:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

Comment: `get :show, id: restaurant`

Comment: With that I get: `Failure/Error: before { get :show, id: restaurant }
     ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound:
       Couldn't find Restaurant`

Comment: `Couldn't find Restaurant` raise because you `build_*`, restaurant instead of  `create_*`.

Comment: @Зелёный Won't I run into a duplication error if I'm validating uniqueness for my Restaurant model though?

Comment: if you don't save to database a record, you not able to fetch it by the show action. To avoid uniqueness errors use `database-cleaner`

Comment: There's no way to fake an id?

Comment: `build_stubbed` fakes the ID - but your controller actually has to fetch the record from the database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`get` takes a action and hash of params (among other things). It will not implicitly take a model and turn it into `{ id: model.to_param }`.

Instead you need to specify the parameters explicitly.

```
describe RestaurantsController do
  let(:restaurant) { create(:restaurant) }

  subject { response }

  describe 'GET #show' do
    before { get :show, id: restaurant }
    it { should render_template('show') }
  end
end
```

As @Зелёный has already mentioned you need to actually persist the record to the database to be able to use it in a controller spec.

To avoid the duplication issue and test ordering issues you should empty the database between each example. The [database_cleaner](https://github.com/DatabaseCleaner/database_cleaner) gem is invaluable for that task.

Also if you need to create several records in the same spec you can use sequences in factory girl:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :user do
    email { |n| "test-#{n}@example.com" }
  end
end
```

The gem [ffaker](https://github.com/ffaker/ffaker) is great for generating emails, usernames etc.

### Added:

You can setup shortcuts for FactoryGirl by including its methods in your `rails_helper`:

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  # ...
  config.include FactoryGirl::Syntax::Methods
end
```

This lets you use the FactoryGirl methods without typing the module name like so:

```
let(:restaurant) { create(:restaurant) }
```

Comment: What exactly does `subject { response }` do?

Comment: Also, for line two of your answer it needs to be `let(:restaurant) { FactoryGirl.create(:restaurant) }` in order for the test to work. Once that's fixed I'll be more than happy to mark this answer as correct.

Comment: Just include the FactoryGirl syntax in your rails helper instead. `subject { response }` sets the subject to be the response object instead of the controller. Its required if you want to write one-liners like `it { should have_http_status :success }`

Comment: Thanks so much for your help.

Comment: You shouldn't need `subject { response }` -- `render_template` should work on a controller instance (which is the default subject in a controller test).